# Django 2.0 - iexact translates to LIKE and not ILIKE

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'
```

and I write the query:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(title__iexact='hello world')
print(articles.query)
```

The output is:

```
SELECT ... FROM `article` WHERE `article`.`title` LIKE hello world
```

You can see `iexact` is translated to LIKE. But django documentation says it will translate to ILIKE, who's wrong?

By the way:

1. my mysql collation is utf8_bin.
2. mysql is serviced on ubuntu.
3. code is running on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentations says [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) that the SQL equivalent of `iexact` is `ILIKE`. It doesn't say `iexact` will translate in MySQL to `ILIKE`. That's also not possible at all. MySQL has no `ILIKE`. `LIKE` is already case insensitive.

In PostgreSQL, which I use, `iexact` translates to:

```
SELECT ... FROM "article" WHERE UPPER("article"."title"::text) = UPPER(hello world)
```

The difference between `exact` and `iexact` in MySQL is the following:

- articles = Article.objects.filter(title__iexact='hello world')

`` ... WHERE `articles`.`title` LIKE hello world ``

- articles = Article.objects.filter(title__exact='hello world')

`` ... WHERE `articles`.`title` = hello world ``

Comment: Thank you very much.So Can I understand `iexact` is equal to `=` in MySQL,except performance?

Comment: @NunchakusHuang No, `iexact` is `LIKE`, `exact` is `=`. It's not about performance, it's about case (insenstive vs. sensitive).

Comment: Thany you again! I have another question now,As you say,`LIKE` is `case insenstive`.I update  'collation' to 'utf8_bin',and the value is 'Hello World' in MySQL,`iexact='hello world'` still can not fetch data,why?

Comment: @NunchakusHuang `utf8_bin` in MySQL is case sensitive, so that's the expected behaviour. Before you start playing with the collations, you have to understand what is their purpose. What kind of characters do you want to save? What is your use-case? Please read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html) and keep in mind: **Don't break the rules if you don't master them.**

Comment: @NunchakusHuang you should upvote the question if you liked the answer :)